# android – show a button for a limited time

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, fadeout

I am making an app where an `ImageButton` is shown and fades until it disappears if the user doesn't touch it for too long.
I tried many different solutions (animation, `wait()`, etc.) but nothing did what I tried to...
It should work like a `Toast`, just show up for 3 seconds and then fade out (in the end of the process the visibility should be `GONE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `timer` and `alpha`

```
long duration = 5000 // 5 seconds
long tick = 100 // 0.1 seconds;

new CountDownTimer(duration, tick) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mImageButton.setAlpha(millisUntilFinished / (float)duration)
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         mImageButton.setAlpha(1); // incase you want to show the button again
     }
}.start();
```

> setAlpha() - Sets the opacity of the view. This is a value from 0 to 1, where 0 means the view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is completely opaque.

Comment: The `ImageButton` only shows for 0.1 sec and then disappears and never reappears (even if I trigger it back with `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`...

Comment: Sorry @Dotan adjusted answer

Comment: there is one problem now... If i trigger the button to be visible in les than 3 seconds then it flashes and does all kinds of glitchy stuff... Do you have any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: GLitchy how sorry?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Toast object, set its View as per the look and feel of the Button. For reference you can see : http://techblogon.com/custom-toast-android-example-with-source-code-description/  and   http://www.javatpoint.com/android-custom-toast-example
You can also extend Toast.java and in the public constructor can set the view.

Comment: I'd like it to be clickable and rounded... is this possible with a toast?

Comment: yes. When you setView then you can set the background image (like the way you want , rounded corners) and in the View you can set touch and click listeners...

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for...<br />
@Joe Maher's answer did it right...<br />
thanks anyways (:

Comment: yes I read his answer, it will work perfectly as per your requirement. My way is yet another way to do it.. it will also show the button (with click actions) and will disappear in case not clicked. But anyways Joe's answer is more elegant...

Comment: Haha I'm just too lazy to test your solution after his worked... In a glance it looks really good too (:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
yourImageButton.animate()
    .alpha(0)
    .setStartDelay(3000)
    .setDuration(1000)
    .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {


        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            yourImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```

This uses [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) and will fade the Button out after 3000ms.
In case the Animation finishes, on AnimationEnd() will be called and will set the Visibility to Gone.
In your onClickMethod you can optionally cancel() the Animation;
Keep in mind that if you set Visibility to GONE, you can't simply go back to VISIBLE state, you have to instantiate the ImageButton again. Better use :

```
.setVisibilty(View.INVISIBLE);
```